# SVN folder cannot merge into itself or anything branched from it

Tags: svn

I have a folder in SVN that seems to have an identity crisis. I can check it out and branch it, but any merging fails.

```
svn co http://svn/myrepo
cd myrepo
svn merge .
```

The above produces something like this (abbreviated):

```
--- Merging r33050 through r36572 into '.':
   C Gemfile.lock
   C test_source/src/...
Skipped missing target: 'test_source/libs'
 G   test_source/src
 G   test_source
Skipped missing target: 'source/Rakefile'
Skipped missing target: 'source/Gemfile'
Skipped missing target: 'source/libs'
Skipped missing target: 'source/Gemfile.lock'
   C source/src/...
 G   source
   C Rakefile
   C Gemfile
 G   .
Summary of conflicts:
  Tree conflicts: 26
  Skipped paths: 5
```

Similarly, if I branch from this folder `svn cp http://svn/myrepo http://svn/myrepo2`, then the branch similarly cannot merge into itself, nor can the trunk merge into it or vice versa.

All that said, `svn up` still works fine.

I feel I must've done something bad in this history. Is there any way to repair this or any places I can investigate further? I'd rather not export/import if I can avoid it. Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with "svn merge ."? I don't think merging something with itself makes sense.

Comment: @stmax: I admit I may be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here, but I believe the failure the merge an SVN folder into itself is reflective of the issue that's preventing me from copying the folder to another location (how you conventionally branch in SVN) and merging this folder's changes into the copy. That produces an identical tree conflict issue when trying to accomplish the merge.

Comment: There might be something wrong with the merge infos of this branch.. maybe you forgot to commit them some time? You can try to use svn merge with the -r switch to manually specify the revisions you want to merge and the --ignore-ancestry switch to ignore all (possibly corrupted) merge infos. Make sure you only specify revisions that do not yet exist in the target branch, that would lead to errors since merge infos are disabled and it'd try to merge the same changes twice. Sorry I'm only guessing, it's hard to tell without being able to look at the repo.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried that here and it doesn't work as well.  As far as I understand it, what the command does is probably not what you intend.

`svn help merge` says:

> This form is called a 'sync' (or 'catch-up') merge:
>
> svn merge SOURCE[@REV] [TARGET_WCPATH]
>
> A sync merge is used to fetch all the latest changes made on a parent
>   branch. In other words, the target branch has originally been created
>   by copying the source branch, and any changes committed on the source
>   branch since branching are applied to the target branch. This uses
>   merge tracking to skip all those revisions that have already been
>   merged, so a sync merge can be repeated periodically to stay up-to-
>   date with the source branch.

So by this command you ask svn to try to apply all changes of the path "." (which, I guess, translates to "http://svn/myrepo") to the current WC.  This must fail, of course.

I fail to see what useful service you want to do with this command.  If you want to "import" the latest changes, a simple `svn up` would integrate all new changes from the server into your WC.

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree with all commenters here that the merge command you did does not make any sense I wanted to take a closer look. So I also tried myself and completely fail to get a result as what you describe.

For me that command `svn merge .` right after a checkout simply does nothing - as excepted. Now I wonder where those changes merged in your case come from. There is something odd in your example.

*If* you really did those three steps one after another (checkout, cd, merge), then *usually* there are no changes available to be merged. So where do those two revisions r33050 & r36572 come from? `svn merge` uses three locations: two 'source' locations, whos difference (the revisions) is merged into the third, the 'target' location. The syntax actually allows to omit an explicit specification of a separate target. But then there cannot be any differences between source and target, *except* when the repository state of the location the checkout was derived from has changed in the mean time. In *that* case the output you cite is expected, but you certainly would have said if 3500 revisions were committed between your checkout and the merge attempt.

So there must be something different in your setup. Can you really exclude the possibility that the repository has changed between checkout and merge? Maybe the repositoy is not maintained by you? Maybe some backup has just reloaded by importing all revisions? Or maybe the location has been moved inbetween? Those things would explain the output, if not in detail then at least in general.

Without any changes on the repository side I get what one would expect:

```
$> svn co https://.../[...]
$> cd [...]
$> svn merge . 
$>
```

My conclusion: one of these:

- the repository has been changed between your checkout and your merge.
- you repository internally uses some unsupported networking like NFS in the file system which always produces 'interesting' artefacts.
- the url has been changed between checkout and merge (maybe an alias or redirection?).
- you omitted some information about what you did that lead to the result you cite.
- you have some hook attached, maybe by svn properties, that take some of the above action.
- a `svn switch` command was issued at the checkout or another `svn merge`, possibly Backwards
- you simply did not checkout the head, but some point in time 3500 revisions in the past.